# Getting list of all Filter options for Items

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, user-experience

I'm displaying up to hundreds of items to a user. The list is paginated for UX and performance reasons. However, a list of filters for ALL items` metadata is needed.

I'm using Pub/Sub pattern to retrieve my paginated records. Currently, the only way I can see retrieving my filter options is to do an initial subscribe to just get those first.

I.e.

1. Subscribe to retrieve list of unique metadata for ALL items (Just do a Projection to get the data I need..could be inefficient because of possibility of hundreds of records)
2. Then do my paginated subscription to just get the list of items that I need at that point in time

This is redundant because I'm subscribing to the same collection twice.

I was also thinking of perhaps caching the data somewhere else. However, since these filters are dynamic because they're based on data itself.

Is there a desired pattern to tackle the UX with regards to performance here?

Comment: What's the pub/sub model? Is it Observable?

Comment: I'm using Meteor JS and so the Pub/Sub model is just Reactive MongoDB Collections. I just tried my solution above and confirmed that it'll get ALL Items because of #1. So this could cause the app to crash once the list grows to hundreds (which is why I had to implement pagination in the first place)